# how to "start conditional" process jbpm7?

Tags: drools, jbpm

I'm new in jbpm wb and trying to start a business process with "Start Conditional" event. but the code 500 is returned and de message "There is no start node that matches the trigger none". In the condition the is a simple drools code like this: control(name=="EXECUTOR").
I try using a simple start event and checking de value of control.name, and it's ok. 
How start conditional event works? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to get all details from your description, but as general approach based on the BPMN standard on Conditional Start Event:

> This type of event is triggered when a condition such as “S&P 500 changes by more than 10% since opening,” or “Temperature above 300C” become true. The condition Expression for the **Event** MUST become false and then true before the **Event** can be triggered again.
>   The Condition Expression of a **Conditional Start Event** MUST NOT refer to the data context or instance attribute of the **Process** (as the **Process** instance has not yet been created). Instead, it MAY refer to static Process attributes and states of entities in the environment. The specification of mechanisms to access such states is out of scope of the standard.

So, in order to start your business process you need to make the condition expression to be evaluated to true value and then raise the event.